Find a counterexample: for $a,b \in K \setminus\{0\}$, equation $ax^2 + b y^2 = 1$ has a solution iff $ax^2 + by^2 = z^2$ has a nontrivial solution
It is a well-known fact that if $\text{char}(K) \neq 2$ and $a,b \in K \setminus\{0\}$, then the equation $ax^2 + by^2 = 1$ has a solution over $K$ if and only if the homogeneous equation $ax^2 + by^2 = z^2$ has a nontrivial solution. The proof uses the fact that $\text{char}(K) \neq 2$, and so I was wondering if someone can help me find an explicit counterexample of a field $K$ of characteristic 2.
To be clear, the only nontrivial implication in this result is that if we have $ax_0^2 + by_0^2 = 0$ for some nontrivial $x_0,y_0 \in K$, then $ax^2 + by^2 = 1$ also has a solution. This can be proved in case of $\text{char}(K) \neq 2$ with relative easy by finding a solution to the system of linear equations: $$ \begin{cases} x - \alpha y = 1/a, \\ x + \alpha y = 1, \end{cases}$$ where $\alpha = x_0 / y_0$. The solution exists because the determinant is $2 \alpha \neq 0$.
Clearly, the field $K$ cannot be finite, because over finite fields the equation $ax^2 + by^2 = 1$ always has a solution, and the implication $\implies$ is of course trivial in the iff above. My knowledge of infinite fields with characteristic 2 is not that great, so all help is welcome :). Thanks in advance!

I feel like I'm missing some context.  Is the non-trivial implication just "If $ax^2 + by^2 = 0$ has a nontrivial solution, then $ax^2 + by^2 = 1$ has a solution"?  (if so, we should probably refine the question to just ask that.  If not, then we might need to clarify the context, like where the solution lies)

Yes, I will add that to my question to make it more clear. Thanks for the remark.

So you want there to be a nontrivial solution to $ax^2 + by^2 = 0$ but no solution to $ax^2 + by^2 = 1$. Try thinking about what this says in characteristic $2$ when $a = b = c^{-1}$...

@IzaakvanDongen Thanks, so if $a = b \neq 0$ and $c = a^{-1}$,  then $ax^2 + b y^2 = 0$ indeed has a nontrivial solution, namely $(1,1)$.  But I am not so sure what this means for $ax^2 + b y^2 = 1,$ that is, $x^2 + y^2 = c$. The problem in finite fields of characteristic 2 is that $x \mapsto x^2$ is a ring isomorphism, so in particular $c$ is a square and so a solution would be given by $(\sqrt{c},0)$.  The only other field of characteristic 2 that I know (and is not algebraically closed) would be the rational functions over $\mathbb{F}_2$, is it in this direction that I should look?

Yes, exactly: you need to find a $c$ which is not a square, and $\Bbb F_2(t)$ is the right place to look. (Though I think you mean "homomorphism" not "isomorphism"!!)

@IzaakvanDongen Okay thank you, indeed in Characteristic 2 $x^2 + y^2 = c$ would imply $(x+y)^2 = c$ so having an element that is not a square proves that $x^2 + y^2 = c$ has no solution.  So: to find an element in $\mathbb{F}_2(t)$ that is not a square, just take $t \in \mathbb{F}_2(t)$?

Yes, indeed. I just realised that I misread your comment (sorry!) - you are right to say that the squaring map is an isomorphism in finite fields. I was already thinking about infinite fields, where what we need is exactly that it can fail to be an isomorphism. Feel free to self-post an answer if you work out the details, if you like!

With the help of @IzaakvanDongen I have found the following counterexample: let $K$ be any field of characteristic 2 that contains an element $c \in K$ which is not a square. (In particular, $K$ must be infinite since $x \mapsto x^2$ is a ring isomorphism for finite $K$. Also $K$ cannot be the algebraic closure of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$ since every element is trivially a square in an algebraically closed field.) We may take $K = \mathbb{F}_2(X)$, the field of formal rational functions in $X$. This is a field with nonsquares, for example take $c = X$.
Once we have obtained such a $K$ and $c$, we can give the counterexample. Remark that $c^{-1} x^2 + c^{-1} y^2 = 0$ has a solution, namely $(1,1)$. However, $c^{-1}x^2 + c^{-1} y^2 = 1$ does not have a solution, for if it did, $$(x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 = c$$ implies that $c$ is a square, a contradiction.
